# Map One data.frame to another

Tags: r

Given `df1` which is a subset of `df2` (less number of cols):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Species = letters[1:10])
df2 <- iris
```

I want to map `df1` to have equal number of columns as `df2` with the same colnames.
My solution:

```
mapDf <- function(df, dfToMap) {

  result <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(dfToMap), nrow = nrow(df)))
  colnames(result) <- colnames(dfToMap)

  for(c in colnames(dfToMap)) {
    if(c %in% colnames(df)) {
      result[, c] <- df[, c]
    }
  }

  result
}
```

test:

```
mapDf(df1, df2)
```

Any ideas how to simplify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify it with

```
map_data_frames <- function(df1, df2, fill = NA) {
   cols <- colnames(df2) %in% colnames(df1)
   df1[names(df2[!cols])] <- fill
   df1[, colnames(df2)] #From @zx8754 in comments      
}

map_data_frames(df1, df2)

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1            NA          NA           NA          NA       a
#2            NA          NA           NA          NA       b
#3            NA          NA           NA          NA       c
#4            NA          NA           NA          NA       d
#5            NA          NA           NA          NA       e
#6            NA          NA           NA          NA       f
#7            NA          NA           NA          NA       g
#8            NA          NA           NA          NA       h
#9            NA          NA           NA          NA       i
#10           NA          NA           NA          NA       j
```

Comment: You might want to reorder columns.

Comment: yeee, whaa about ordering? In my example data.frames should the same order of columns

Comment: @stakowerflol  change the last line in his function to `df1[ , colnames(df2) ]`

Comment: Ronak Shah can I use your function in my commercial project?

Answer (score 3):

With data.table....

```
library(data.table)
res = setDT(df2[NA_integer_, ])[df1, on=names(df1)]
setcolorder(res, names(df2))

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 1:           NA          NA           NA          NA       a
 2:           NA          NA           NA          NA       b
 3:           NA          NA           NA          NA       c
 4:           NA          NA           NA          NA       d
 5:           NA          NA           NA          NA       e
 6:           NA          NA           NA          NA       f
 7:           NA          NA           NA          NA       g
 8:           NA          NA           NA          NA       h
 9:           NA          NA           NA          NA       i
10:           NA          NA           NA          NA       j
```

(I'm not sure if the `setcolorder` is necessary or if `res` will already have the same col order as `df2`.)

The idea for a "missing slice" of an object `x[NA_integer_,]` or an "empty slice" `x[0L,]` can also be found in the vetr package, where the latter is referred to as a "template". (I'm not sure whether that'll be useful for OP's use-case or not.)